# R getSymbols error: trying to download stock data but function returns ocassionally HTTP error 400

Tags: r, quantmod, http-error

some background: I am trying to do some analysis on US stocks and I need historic prices of all the publicly traded US stocks. I am importing the data from Yahoo Finance. There are roughly 2900 stocks so the error I am receiving wouldn't be a huge issue if it only appeared few dozen times on some small companies but now it's happening maybe 15 % of the time. Basically the error leads to lack of necessary data.

The code I am using:

```
library(quantmod)
#I have appropriate data that does read and work correctly
data <- scan("list_of_tickers_with_apostrophies.txt", what = character())

tickers <- c(data)

ENV.STOCK <- new.env()

getSymbols(
           tickers, 
           src = "yahoo", 
           from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), 
           to = as.Date("2020-01-01"), 
           periodicity = "daily", 
           env = ENV.STOCK)
```

The error code is for example NAUT's case the following:

```
Warning: NAUT download failed; trying again.
Warning: Unable to import “NAUT”.
NAUT download failed after two attempts. Error message:
HTTP error 400.
```

As stated, for most of the cases the code works fine, but the requests should be working 99% of the time for my analysis to be valid later on. Otherwise way too much value is lost/missing if we are considering the total space of US stocks and their combined market cap.

What can I do? Can I fix the code or is the issue at Yahoo's end? Should I use some other libraries to get the desired data?

Edit:
got the code working by changing the `to = as.Date("2020-01-01")` into `to = Sys.Date()+1`.
This for me suggests that the issue is with UTF encoding or something related to dates and HTTP. Although this fixes the issue, I still want to have the data from 2010 until today. So there needs to be a workaround for the date issue, and I don't know how.

Comment: Yahoo Finance doesn't provide historical data for every security. A 404 means the website can't be found (i.e. Yahoo doesn't provide the data).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks for your answer. This may be offtopic for Stack Overflow and geared more towards Quant Stack Exchange, but I'll ask anyways: are there any other open source stock data sites that are available for the usage in R? In the future I'll have access to all of the fanciest sites provided by my university but not yet, or even the near future, but I would still like to try different things on my own.

Comment: I prefer [tiingo](https://api.tiingo.com/). They might not have every security either, but the API is more stable and the data is better quality.